# C Library for PushBullet

Tags: c, notifications

Today I wrote a quick little header to implement pushbullet support into C. It is working fairly nicely but I am no programmer so it isn't very well written and a few features are broken. 
For anyone interested in using this library or helping me with it, please have a look at it on https://github.com/CarlNeuhaus/C-library-for-Pushbullet

Comment: `.h` files contain prototypes. For definitions you use `.c` files.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I wanted it to be as simple as possible so all you had to do was include the .h file but I will think about separating them.